# Can I use an array of integers as a record field in Delphi?

Tags: arrays, delphi, record

I am reading a text file into a record array.  Part of the data in the text files are program grades and test grades.  Can I declare an array of integers to fold the program or test values as a field in the record?  If so, then how do I access the individual program values in the field?
For example, could I declare the record like this?  And if so how would I input or access data from say test[3]?

```
nametype = record
  first : string[10];
  mi : string[3];
  last : string[30];
end;
stype = record
  id : integer;
  name : nametype;
  prog : array[1..10] of integer;
  test : array[1..3] of integer;
  progave, quizave : real;
  average : double;
  grade : char;
end;
sarraytype = array[1..100] of stype;
var
  student : sarraytype;
```

So I guess where I'm stuck is reading into these arrays.  So far for my read I have:

```
procedure TstudentData.openButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
   begin
     var i : integer;
     if open.execute then
     begin
      assignfile(inf,open.FileName);
      reset(inf);
      i := 1;
      while not eof(inf) do with student[i] do
      begin
         readln(inf, id, name.first, name.mi, name.last);
         i := i + 1;
      end;
   end;
   i:=1;
end;
```

I have the read for the other data, but I'm at a total loss for how to read into the prog and test arrays.

Comment: Yes you can do this? Did you try?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can. By an example ...

```
var
  a: sarraytype;
  i, j: integer;
begin
  for i := low(a) to High(a) do
    for j := low(a[i].test) to High(a[i].test) do
      a[i].test[j] := i * 100 + j;
  for i := low(a) to High(a) do
    for j := low(a[i].test) to High(a[i].test) do
      Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(a[i].test[j]));

end;
```

as response to your comment

```
var
  a,b: sarraytype;
  i, j: integer;
  fs:TFileStream;
begin
  for i := low(a) to High(a) do
    begin
    for j := low(a[i].test) to High(a[i].test) do
      a[i].test[j] := i * 100 + j;
    a[i].name.first := 'Test' + IntToStr(i);
    end;

  fs := TFileStream.Create('C:\temp\test.bin',fmCreate);
  try
  fs.Write(a,sizeOf(a));
  finally
    fs.Free;
  end;

  fs := TFileStream.Create('C:\temp\test.bin',fmopenRead);
  try
  fs.Read(b,sizeOf(b));
  finally
    fs.Free;
  end;

  for i := low(b) to High(b) do
    begin
    memo1.Lines.Add(b[i].name.first);
    for j := low(b[i].test) to High(b[i].test) do
      Memo1.Lines.Add(IntToStr(b[i].test[j]));

    end;

end;
```

BTW:

Usual naming would be

```
Tnametype = record
  first : string[10];
  mi : string[3];
  last : string[30];
end;
Tstype = record
  id : integer;
  name : nametype;
  prog : array[1..10] of integer;
  test : array[1..3] of integer;
  progave, quizave : real;
  average : double;
  grade : char;
end;

Tsarraytype = array[1..100] of stype;
```

Comment: This answer says it all :)

Comment: IMO usual naming should be: TName = record ... and TStudent = record omitting the "type" in the identifier as that's what the "T" is for.